# How to calculate the area (or Time) spent in each "zone" on a stacked area graph?

Tags: r, data-visualization, dataset

I have a dataset of blood pressure recordings measured over 36 hours, which I plotted with BP (aka MAP) on the Y axis, and minutes on the X axis. I then plotted the blood pressure percentiles for age (horizontal lines - 1st%ile, through 99th%ile) running across the graph. I filled in the entire area under the blood pressure tracing using geom_area, and then shaded in the area under the 10th% and 50th%iles. I would like to calculate how much time the person spent with a blood pressure in each "zone". Ie. how many minutes did this patient have a blood pressure less than the 50th%ile? less than the 10th?

Is this possible with this stacked area graph?

[image]

I am a beginner beginner. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain more about the data? The points are irregularly spaced and linearly interpolated (straight lines drawn between successive points) in the plot, which may not be entirely reasonable.